# Как включить в ссылку массив?

Tags: javascript, php, json, веб-программирование

У меня вопрос, возможно ли такое, мне нужно включить в ссылку массив который передает ID заказа.

$url = 'https://api.telegram.org/XXXXXXXXXXXXXtokenXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/sendMessage?chat_id=XXXXXXXXX&text=Получен%20новый%20заказ №';

Эта ссылка приводит к отправке сообщения "Получен новый заказ №"

И есть массив $order_id

Как мне правильно это написать что бы отправлялось сообщение и номер заказа ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ordersStr = implode(',', $order_id);
```

А дальше этот `$ordersStr` конкатенируете с указанной строкой

Comment: А как скантоктировать его ? $ordersStr такой же массив :)) с которым как и с $orders я не знаю что делать

Comment: @Илья неправда. $ordersStr - это строка.  А строки конкатенировать любой умеет

Comment: $url = 'https://api.telegram.org/XXXXXXXXXXXXXtokenXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/sendMessage?chat_id=XXXXXXXXX&text=Получен%20новый%20заказ № $ordersStr '; Так ?

Comment: @Илья если через **двойные кавычки** то да - так. Если через одинарные то `$url = '.....someString' . $ordersStr`;

Comment: Написал так Получен%20новый%20заказ № '.$ordersStr'; у меня ошибка, если не трудно, напишите строку как она должна быть

Comment: потому что у вас лишняя кавычка перед точкой с запятой

Comment: Благодарю за помощь, просто сделал так` $url = 'https://api.telegram.org/XXXXXXXXXXXXXtokenXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/sendMessage?chat_id=XXXXXXXXX&text=Получен%20новый%20заказ №' .$order_id ;`